# Remote server returned an unexpected response :(417) Expectation Failed: Using MS Translator API in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, microsoft-translator

I am trying sample code of Microsoft Translator in Windows Store App from this  [link](http://eren.ws/2013/03/12/using-microsoft-translator-in-windows-store-apps/)

The sample code is given  [here](http://sdrv.ms/YiK4HU)

When I run the app, I get an exception "The remote server returned an unexpected response :(417) Expectation Failed"

This exception occurs on the following line:

```
germanTranslationTextBlock.Text = await webService.TranslateAsync("Bearer " + accessToken.access_token, sourceTextBox.Text, "en", "de", "text/plain", "");
```

P.S. I am behind a proxy.
Some googling shows that `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;` is the solution but I do not know how to do that for Windows Store App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not solve this error, but got a better and infact best source code [which works successfully] for doing text to speech and translate too  [here](http://translatorservice.codeplex.com/releases/view/97104).

Could have saved a lifetime if I would have found it earlier, but it's really hard to find any good resources for windows app development.